# sh: 39: source: not found While installing oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, ubuntu-12.04

On my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I was trying to install oh-my-zsh by following command found on github oh-my-zsh project page.

`wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | sh`

But I'm getting the following error.
Tried with sudo, same result.

`` Looking for an existing zsh config...
Found ~/.zshrc. [0;32]Backing up to ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh
Using the Oh My Zsh template file and adding it to ~/.zshrc
Copying your current PATH and adding it to the end of ~/.zshrc for you.
Time to change your default shell to zsh!
Password: chsh: PAM authentication failed
         __                                     __

  __  / /_     _ __  __  __   __  _/ /_

 / __ / __ \   / __ `__ / / / /  /_  / / / _ \ 
/ // / / / /  / / / / / / // /    / /(  ) / / / 
_// //  // // //_, /    //// //

                        /_/ ``

....is now installed.
sh: 39: source: not found

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out.
Last line of install.sh is `/usr/bin/env zsh
source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Yep. You can fix this by executing ```chsh -s $(which zsh)```

Answer (score 4):

The error `sh: 39: source: not found` is only part of the problem. The output you posted also indicates problems related to changing the default shell: `Password: chsh: PAM authentication failed`.

The same problem is reported [in this issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1315).

You should follow the manual installation steps provided on [oh-my-zsh github page](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) (or [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1315)).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved by running the `ohmyz.sh` script manually:

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh/
curl -L http://install.ohmyz.sh > install.sh
sh install.sh
```

[source](http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2014/10/how-to-install-oh-my-zsh-on-ubuntu-14/)